# what is different between call function with parameters and call function with return value of other parameters

Tags: javascript, function

**if I have function like this**

```
function cloneObj( obj ) {
    return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
}



function test( obj ) {
    console.log(obj);
}

var x = {1:2};
```

**what is different between call function by this way**

```
 test(cloneObj(x));
```

**or call this function by this way**

```
var y = cloneObj(x); 
test(y);
```

Comment: What..... there is no difference. The first you take a reference, the second you don't bother....

Comment: Side note: That's both an inefficient and inaccurate way to clone an object.

Comment: Remember, [functions are first class objects in JavaScript](http://timmknight.github.io/2015/first-class-functions-javascript/).

Comment: @Rohit Even in languages where that's not the case, that would not change the answer to this question…

Comment: For sure, I just want OP to go through it :)

Comment: @Rohit416: When someone asks a question about X, bringing up something completely unrelated really isn't useful. It's just confusing to the person asking the question (and others, like deceze above). E.g.: "My car has trouble starting on cold days, any idea why?" Comment: "Remember to keep your tyre pressure within the recommended range." Questioner (and everyone else): ???

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, okay will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference at all, other than in the second example you create a `y` variable and keep a reference to the cloned object in it, and in the first you don't (once your code is complete, the cloned object no longer has any strong<sup>1</sup> references to it and can be garbage-collected).

---

<sup>1</sup> The console keeps a reference to the object when you log it, but I assume it's a weak reference that doesn't prevent GC (and it *is* an assumption, not something I know for a fact).